# Why am I getting handshake_failure with Java SSL cert?

Tags: java, ssl, hudson, ssl-certificate, svnkit

I'm trying to use Hudson (which uses SVNKit) to access a Subversion repository that requires a client certificate to access it. I can access the same repository using the same client certificate via Eclipse (also using SVNKit).

When Hudson tries to check out the repository, it fails with:

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Hudson is running under Tomcat, so I turned on ssl debugging in the Tomcat log (`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`).

At the end of the handshake I see:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
Executor #0 for master : executing eMASS integration #3, SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  warning, description = no_certificate
```

I'm not sure if that is the crux of the problem or not.

That follows a list of Cert Authorities. I made sure the server's cert root issuer is imported in my `cacerts`, as well as the intermediate issuer. I still get the same problem.

Any ideas for what to look at?

The [log is on pastebin](http://coveros.pastebin.com/m1bf7e767).

Comment: The problem was that Hudson had a bug in that it did not read the client cert even after it prompted for it. It was fixed in Hudson 1.342. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several bugs in Hudson's subversion plugin involving dealing with SSL certs and their passwords. Here's the one I reported, which they have fixed: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5230. So now, it should properly save the cert you upload.

Upgrade to the latest version of Hudson (Hudson ver. 1.342 or later) and also the latest version of the subversion plugin (1.10, available at https://hudson.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentView?documentID=147307&showInfo=true).  To install this plugin, download the subversion.hpi file, then in Hudson go to Manage Hudson -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced, and upload it.  Then you need to restart Hudson.

Comment: That was it. It now works for me.

In the meantime, I had added my cert to the /var/lib/hudson/.subversion/servers file. See https://wiki.svnkit.com/SVNKit_specific_system_properties and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers

Answer (score 0):

Alexey had the right idea.

Log:

```
SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  warning, description = no_certificate
```

This was discussed [in the 
Java Programming forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=276025&tstart=112711).

Maybe your eclipse and Hudson start with different JREs (client JRE vs. JDK JRE?). Every JRE has its own keystore. This can get quit confusing to configure.

Comment: They are on different systems, so they are definitely different keystores. On Eclipse, where I can connect, I have added no certs to the cacert. On the Hudson box I have added the server cert issuing authorities to the cacert file.

Comment: Are these different JDK versions? The root certificates change from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Ubuntu server. Installation of certificates did not help. The solution was to chage the default Java (java-6-openjdk) to Sun Java (java-6-sun).

Answer (score -1):

I don`t know exactly, but may be it helps.
May be you need to add cerificate to jvm using keystore